# How can I draw an image in a static area in an MFC dialog?

Tags: c++, mfc

In an MFC dialog I have a static area and assigned an id: `IDC_STATIC`. How can I connect  this `IDC_STATIC` id with the handler (`HWND`) such that my image will draw inside the static text area?

```
HWND   g_hWnd3      = NULL;
HDC    g_hDC3       = NULL;

g_hDC3 = ::GetDC( g_hWnd3 );
```

How can I pass the static text id as a `GetDC()` argument?

Comment: You may wish to reconsider the tags you added to this question; they help other users find questions that interest them so a properly tagged question will get better response than a badly tagged question. You can [edit the tags](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26605485/edit) yourself if you wish to.

Comment: You should give your static control unique ID instead of IDC_STATIC. Then you can handle [`WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It gives you `HDC` as `wParam` and `lParam` is `HWND`. This is `winapi` and `c` solution, I don't know `mfc` but if you grasp this concept you can do it yourself in `mfc`. Best regards.

Comment: MFC way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7w5x74z.aspx `CStatic::SetBitmap` Note that static control must have `SS_BITMAP` style.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider deriving your own class from CStatic. The advantage to this approach is that you can control all of the rendering to the control from one self contained class.  In particular, if you define the static control with the *SS_OWNERDRAW* style, you will be able to handle its rendering in [CStatic::DrawItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfeckw5x.aspx).  When DrawItem is called, you will receive a pointer to the DrawItemStruct, which has embedded in it, a handle to the control's DC that you can use to render into the control.